# program crashes in two simple inherent classes. C# Beginner

Tags: c#, class, oop, constructor, radix

i just started c# couple hours ago and I saw techniques for creating classes in c#. I made my own two classes Animal and Dog, where Dog inherit Animal. My code has no error but still my program crashes on execution. I have a little knowledge about oop. Am I missing something important here in this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultipleClasses
{
    class Animal
    {
        public int hands;
        public Boolean feathers;
        public int legs;
        public int getlegs(){ return legs; }
        public void setlegs(int l){this.legs = l;}
        public void sethands(int h){this.hands = h;}
        public int gethands(){return this.hands;}
        public void setfeathers(Boolean f){this.feathers = f;}
        public Boolean getfeathers(){return this.feathers;}
        public Animal(int l=0, int h=0, Boolean f=false){
            this.legs = l;
            this.hands = h;
            this.feathers = f;
        }
    }
    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        public string getname(){return this.name;}
        public int getage(){return this.age;}
        public void setname(string n) { this.name = n;}
        public void setage(int g){this.age = g;}

        public Dog(string n, int g, int l, int h, Boolean f) : base(l, h, f)
        {
            this.name = n;
            this.age = g;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog a = new Dog("Jack",5,4,0,false);
            Console.WriteLine("The Dog's name is {0} and age is {1} "+a.getname(),a.getage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some error message would be helpful, unless it's a quiz and we should guess error message

Comment: The code looks technically correct, although in C# we don't write `get...` and `set...` methods but use properties with getters and setters instead. I guess with "crashing" you mean an exception. Please tell us the exception's message and stack trace, which will point you to the line that causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("The Dog's name is {0} and age is {1} "+a.getname(),a.getage());
```

Change the `+` to a `,`

```
Console.WriteLine("The Dog's name is {0} and age is {1} ", a.getname(),a.getage());
```

Output when corrected:

> The Dog's name is Jack and age is 5

There are other issues with the code, namely with the way you've named some things, you probably want to read about getters and setters as well.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy It does throw a `FormatException` if an argument is missing for `"{1}"`

Comment: If I run it with the `+` I get the error `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list`. When changed to a `,` it runs fine. FYI using Linqpad 5 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: @RenéVogt true, upvoting

Comment: Downvoters care to comment? Always looking for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Re write the codes like C# way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultipleClasses
{
   class Animal
   {
      public int hands { get; set; }
      public Boolean feathers { get; set; }
      public int legs { get; set; }
      public Animal(int l = 0, int h = 0, Boolean f = false)
      {
        this.legs = l;
        this.hands = h;
        this.feathers = f;
      }
  }

  class Dog : Animal
  {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public int age { get; set; }
     public Dog(string n, int g, int l, int h, Boolean f)
     {
        this.name = n;
        this.age = g;
        this.legs = l;
        this.hands = h;
        this.feathers = f;
      }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog a = new Dog("Jack", 5, 4, 0, false);
        Console.WriteLine("The Dog's name is {0} and age is {1}", a.name.ToString(), a.age.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```